# How to send data from view to controller in spring boot

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**Objective:**
We have a view page -> index.html (consists of javascript functions)
We have a spring boot controller class.

We trigger localhost:port in web browser, the server captures the url and via controller class, we receive the trigger and execute a function to just display the web page (as mentioned above index.html).

Now after the index.html page is displayed in the web browser, we trigger numerous functionalities through the buttons defined (in javascript) in the index.html file. Consider we have a text box in the index.html page where we generate few text data.

**Problem:**
Objective is to save the data in the above mentioned text box into the database via backend technology. How to pass the data in the text box to the controller class (may be).

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     //definition of save()
 </script>
<button id="btnNew" onclick="new()">New</button>
<button id="btnSave" onclick="save()">Save</button>
<input style="width: 300px" type="text" id="textBox" value=""/>

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    private String input;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model) {
        this.input= retrieveInputParameters();
        model.addAttribute("token", this.input);
        return "index"; //view
    }
}
```

**Description of Code:**

*Controller Class:* As mentioned above, currently the controller class have only 1 method main, which is triggered when the server is hit:
http://localhost:8080

The method retrieves an input parameter and then renders the index.html page.

*index.html:* It consists of multiple buttons with multiple functionality. After clicking on Save button, it triggers a 3rd party url and retrieves data (which has no connection with the server it is running in). Now We want the data retrieved, in the server (controller class).

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We can send the data from view to controller via Ajax:

For example:

```
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                contentType : 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
                dataType : 'json',
                url: "/xyz",
                data: document.getElementById('abc').value,
                success:function(result){

                }
            });
```